# Code=-1011 "Request failed: unauthorized (401)" AFNetwoking

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I'm trying to make a GET request setting a header called

> X-User-Authorization 
>    but I'm getting the following error:
>
> Code=-1011 "Request failed: unauthorized (401)" AFNetwoking

```
 -(void) listarGruposDeDistancia
    {
        NSMutableArray *listaDistancias = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
        manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
        manager.requestSerializer.allowsCellularAccess = YES;
        [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"valueHere" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-User-Authorization"];

       AFSecurityPolicy *policy = [AFSecurityPolicy policyWithPinningMode:AFSSLPinningModeNone];
        policy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;
        manager.securityPolicy = policy;

        NSString *url = @"https://url:3000/api/v0.1/groups/";

        [manager GET:url
          parameters:nil
             success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

                NSLog(@“success”);
                 }
                 [self concluirListaDistancias:listaDistancias];

             } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                 NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
             }];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're definitely getting a 401 back from the server - meaning you haven't constructed an appropriate HTTP request with authentication according to what the server requires. Review the documentation of the (service provider or in your case what appears to be a local packaged product), then use tools like [curl](/questions/tagged/curl) and [postman](/questions/tagged/postman) to construct an appropriate HTTP request. When you're confident the raw requests are working as expected, use something like [requestb.in](http://requestb.in) to test your AFNetworking request.

For what it's worth, `X-User-Authorization` isn't a pre-configured authorization header (The `X-` prefix implies it's a custom header attribute). Maybe you're looking for something more like `Authorization: Bearer <token>`?

Comment: OK - so then make that same API call that works in Postman against requestbin, and then another using AFNetworking. Compare the requests and see what you need to do to your AFNetworking request to fix it.

Comment: [requestbin](https://requestb.in) accepts any HTTP requests - go there and generate a bucket. Swap out the URLs in Postman and your app project and send them there instead.

Comment: If your endpoint is on the Internet (not local), you can also use Runscope. Here's a doc with specific instructions on how to use Runscope URLs with AFNetworking -- an instant proxy that captures all request and response data, so you can see what your client request looks like and what the corresponding response is back from the destination API.  https://www.runscope.com/docs/code-examples/ios

Comment: the difference is that in iOS the server is returning { status code: 401, `    "Www-Authenticate" = "Basic realm=\"Restricted\"";
` in headers...but I don't know why

Comment: Don't look at the response from the server - you need to compare the working and the not-working *request* and work backwards.